# GoogleMap in C# MVC, coordinates not working

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I'm trying to put a googlemap with marker on webpage.

It's not working, other components are loaded just map is just blank screen.

I got HTML source from googlemap api site.

```js
function initMap() {
  var latitude = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["latitude"]));
  var longitude = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["longitude"]));

  latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
  longitude = parseFloat(longitude);

  var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: coord
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coord,
    map: map
  });
}
```

If I put a number in the coordinate, it's working.

So I think It's a data type problem, I'm on this problem for hours.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reading all, right after I post this question I solved the problem.

I just swap the longitude with latitude and it works